# logback.xml does not used

Tags: scala, logging, sbt, logback, slf4j

I'm trying to use logback.xml in my sbt project.
I added the following dependency:

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

I created a logback.xml and located it under:

> /src/main/resources

When I run it on Intellij, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work. 
When I run the jar (not Uber jar), it always doesn't work:

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/***/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/***/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

I believe the issue is related to classpath issue, excluded SLF4J, specified the logback.xml path explicitly, but nothing!

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I excluded "org.slf4j" from all dependencies & plugins, except from "ch.qos.logback", and be doing I avoided multiple slf4j in classpath:

... `.map( _ exclude("org.slf4j", "*")) ++  Seq("ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3")`